# How to use ListLinePlot to plot a multicolored line, where the colors are given by an array?

Tags: plotting, color

I have a 2D dataset with three columns. The first two columns are x and y, the third one is z. I want to plot a line with the colors specified by the z data.

Here is an ideal example, the only problem is that my dataset is not generated from a simple function.

```
data = Table[{x, Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, Range[-3.14, 3.14, 0.2]}]
```

I want to get a plot like this:
[image]

PS:
This picture is generated by

```
ListLinePlot[Table[{x, Sin[x]}, {x, Range[-\[Pi], \[Pi], 0.2]}], 
ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Cos[x]], ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

But in reality I don't have a function `z(x,y)`.

One way I tried is to find the index of  `{x,y}`, but sometimes it fails. I hope there is a better way to solve this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics) directly instead of having [`ListLinePlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListLinePlot) construct the [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics) object for you:

```
data = Table[{x, Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, Range[-3.14, 3.14, 0.2]}];
Graphics[
    {Line[data[[All, ;;2]], VertexColors -> data[[All,3]]]},
    Axes->True,
    AspectRatio->1/GoldenRatio
]
```

[image]

Comment: May I ask how to use another color function? For example the ```Hue``` or ```Opacity``` such that I can change the color freely?

Comment: @Xiaoyu Liu wrap the input to `VertexColors` in whatever you want to use; i.e., something like `VertexColors->Hue[data[[All,3]]]` should work, with modifications as appropriate for your desired use case.

Comment: @ca-trevillian Oh, I got it. ```Hue``` does not accept list.  ```Hue/@data[[All,3]]``` is going to work. Thank you anyway.